# convert to datetime64 format with to_datetime()

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to convert some date time data in to `pandas.to_datetime()` format. It is not working and the type of `df['Time']` is `Object`. Where is wrong?

Please Note that I have attached my time file.

My Code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

f = open('time','r')
lines = f.readlines()

t = []
for line in lines:
    time = line.split()[1][-20:]
    time2 = time[:11] + ' ' +time[12:21]
    t.append(time2)



df = pd.DataFrame(t)
df.columns = ['Time']
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

print df['Time'] 


Name: Time, Length: 16136, dtype: object
```

please find the attach time data file [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B80N3g3ZkIhhUmRJc0R6ams1d0E/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: You'll rally more support if you make it a little easier for us to work with this. Can you paste in just a few lines of data (say, 5) that reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file `time` contain some invalid data.

For example, line 8323 contain `8322 "5/Jul/2013::8:25:18  0530"`,
which is different from normal lines `8321 "15/Jul/2013:18:25:18 +0530"`.

```
8321 "15/Jul/2013:18:25:18 +0530"
8322 "5/Jul/2013::8:25:18  0530"
```

For normal line, `time2` become `15/Jul/2013 18:25:18`, but for invalid line `"5/Jul/2013::8:25:18`

```
15/Jul/2013 18:25:18
"5/Jul/2013::8:25:18
```

Which cause some lines are parsed to datetime, and some lines not; data are coerced to object (to contain both datetime and string).

```
>>> pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(['15/Jul/2013 18:25:18', '15/Jul/2013 18:25:18']))
0   2013-07-15 18:25:18
1   2013-07-15 18:25:18
dtype: datetime64[ns]

>>> pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(['15/Jul/2013 18:25:18', '*5/Jul/2013 18:25:18']))
0    15/Jul/2013 18:25:18
1    *5/Jul/2013 18:25:18
dtype: object
```

---

If you take only first 5 data (which has correct date format) from files, you will get what you expected.

```
...
df = pd.DataFrame(t[:5])
df.columns = ['Time']
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
```

Above code yield:

```
0   2013-07-15 00:00:12
1   2013-07-15 00:00:18
2   2013-07-15 00:00:23
3   2013-07-15 00:00:27
4   2013-07-15 00:00:29
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

**UPDATE**

Added a small example that show the cause of dtype of `object`, not `datetime`.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I removed those entries but still it is not converted to datetime64. Is there a way to find where it fails? Like try..except thing?

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage, Could you upload new version of `time` file?

Comment: May be there are some other things....please refer time2 here.. https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B80N3g3ZkIhhc2tvN1lLR0FvdGc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage, Many invalid lines are still there. Remove or fix them all and run again. (8240L, 8241L, 8371L, 8372L, 8429L, 8430L, ..., 13278L, 13279L)

Comment: Thank you, yes I tried with first 100s of them, which worked perfectly, Is there a way to avoid these lines?

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage, In for loop, do something like `if isinstance(pandas.to_datetime(time2), str): continue` before `t.append(time2)`. (skip invalid lines). This probably make program run slower. Avoid making invalid lines from the beginning is best option.